# Botframework - C# - Adaptive Card - Submit Action - Exception

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

On SubmitAction action in Adaptive Cards (botframework, c#, emulator, localhost) I get this Exception

```
Exception: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stringToEscape
[File of type 'text/plain']
```

Can you help me point out what am doing wrong?

```
card.Actions.Add(
    new SubmitAction()
    {
        Title = "Submit"
        Data = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.FromObject(new { button = "Submit", ServerUrl = "idServerURL" })
    }
);
```

From RootDialog - LUIS Intent is called

```
[LuisIntent("ServerAuth")]
public async Task ServerAuthIntentActionResultHandlerAsync(IDialogContext 
context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
{
    var message = await activity;
    await context.PostAsync($"Am working on it...'{message.Text}' ");

    var serverAuthAction = new ServerAuthAction();

    // Action to execute if no form is required - Based on LUIS result, call fulfillment methods From/To ERP Data and proceed to next stage of dialog
    await serverAuthAction.ResumeActionServerAuthFormDialog(context, result);

    //context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);

}

public async Task ResumeActionServerAuthFormDialog(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    try
    {
        //Based on the LUIS Result, fetch data from AppServer
        //var searchQuery =  result;

        //Data - Assign value to this Model from AppServer fetched data
        ServerAuthModel serverAuthData = new ServerAuthModel();
        serverAuthData = default(ServerAuthModel);

        //For testing populate values by hardcoding - /May/2017
        ServerAuthAdaptiveCardView serverAuthView = new ServerAuthAdaptiveCardView();

        //Pass Data to Channel Adaptive Card View 
        var resultData = serverAuthView.GetServerAuthAdaptiveCard();

        var resultMessage = context.MakeMessage();

        resultMessage.Attachments.Add(resultData);

        await context.PostAsync(resultMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ...
    }
    finally
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

GetServerAuthAdaptiveCard() has the Submit Action code.

```
public Attachment GetServerAuthAdaptiveCard()
{
    AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard();
    card.FallbackText = "App Server Authentication";
    card.Body.Add(
        new TextInput()
        {
            Id = "idServerURL",
            IsRequired = true,
            Placeholder = "App Server URL",
            MaxLength = 100,
            IsMultiline = false,
            Style = TextInputStyle.Url,
            Speak = "App Server URL",
        });

    card.Body.Add(
        new ChoiceSet()
        {
            Id = "idAuthCompany",
            IsRequired = true,
            IsMultiSelect = false,
            Style = ChoiceInputStyle.Compact,
            Speak = "Company to Authenticate for",
            Value = "DocM5",
            Choices = new List<Choice>() {
                new Choice()
                {
                    Title = "P2PDemo",
                    Value = "P2PDemo",
                    IsSelected = true,
                    Speak = "P2PDemo"
                },
                new Choice()
                {
                    Title = "SalesDemo",
                    Value = "SalesDemo",
                    IsSelected = false,
                    Speak = "SalesDemo"
                }
            }
        });
    card.Body.Add(
        new TextInput()
        {
            Id = "idBranchName",
            IsRequired = true,
            Placeholder = "App Branch",
            MaxLength = 100,
            IsMultiline = false,
            Style = TextInputStyle.Text,
            // Value = ""
        });

    var submitActionData = JObject.Parse("{ \"Type\": \"idServerURL\" }");


    card.Actions.Add(
        /*  new SubmitAction()
        {
            Title = "Submit",
            // Speak = "Submit",
            Data = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.FromObject(new { button = "Submit", ServerUrl = "idServerURL" })
        }
        */
        new SubmitAction()
        {
            DataJson = submitActionData.ToString()
        });

    var attachment = new Attachment() { ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType, Content = card };
    return attachment;
}
```

Exception from Emulator:

```
"contentType": "text/plain",
"content": "   at System.Uri.EscapeDataString(String stringToEscape)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.LuisRequest.BuildUri(ILuisModel model)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.LuisService.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.ILuisService.BuildUri(LuisRequest luisRequest)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Extensions.<QueryAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog`1.<MessageReceived>d__8.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__5.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter<T>.GetResult()
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog`1.<ResumeAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
    -- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__5.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IWait<C>-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFiberLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringEventLoop`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.EventLoopDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SetAmbientThreadCulture.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.QueueDrainingDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializeByConversation.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
    at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5.MoveNext()"
```

Comment: Can you add more code for your implementation? thanks

Comment: Hi, yes included from where this is called. thanks

Comment: Please add all the necessary code, for example here your method 'GetServerAuthAdaptiveCard()'  is not detailed

Comment: Included the method implementation

Comment: We need also LuisModel declaration (without real values) as the exception seems no to be in your AdaptiveCard

Comment: @BotHandler, please tell me the message that you are sending to the bot before seeing this error.

Comment: I click Submit before I get this Error. I enter the URL and select the Company and enter Branch (test values)

Comment: The AuthServer  is a simple LUIS Intent having only utterances as "log on to server", "logon", "signin"  with no entities tagged.

Answer (score 2):

Try filling the `DataJson` property instead of the `Data` one.

```
var submitActionData = JObject.Parse("{ \"Type\": \"HotelSelection\" }");

var action = new SubmitAction()
{
    DataJson = submitActionData.ToString()
}
```

#### Update based on new details added to the question.

Per the full exception, the problem is around LUIS and not with the Adaptive card. Specifically, the problem is arising in the [BuildUri](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Luis/LuisService.cs#L133-L203) method of the [LuisService](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Luis/LuisService.cs) class (which is being called by the `LuisDialog`). The exception is also telling us that the problem is happening when the [EscapeDataString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx69i57j0l4.2151j0j7) method is being called.

If you look carefully to the `BuildUri` method, you will see that there are 10 calls to the `EscapeDataString` method. Some of these calls are against values from the service itself, which I don't think you are modifying; however other ones are over values from the `LuisModel`, like `SubscriptionKey` and `ModelId` and also there is one over the `Query` to be sent to `LUIS`.

That being said, my recommendation is to review the values you set in the `LuisModel` attribute that is decorating your `LuisDialog` based class.

If you are unsure how LUIS + Bot Framework works, I would recommend you to take a look at the [intelligence-LUIS](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/intelligence-LUIS) sample.

Comment: hi, still have the same error "text/plain",
      "content": "   at System.Uri.EscapeDataString(String stringToEscape)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.LuisRequest.BuildUri(ILuisModel model)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.LuisService.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.ILuisService.BuildUri(LuisRequest luisRequest)\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Extensions.<QueryAsync>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n

Comment: As @EzequielJadib mentioned, the log is about Luis. Can you explain what you are typing in your emulator, and add more info about your Luis intents?
I just tested the adaptiveCard without LUIS and it's working (even with your initial SubmitAction)

Comment: @BotHandler I just updated my answer with all the details about the error you are getting and my recommendation on where to look at. LMK

Comment: thanks to both of you for the feedback. The same LUIS Model based other intents are working. I have used Receipt Card and Signin Card which is working but not Adaptive Card. As suggested, I will try now without LUIS Model and give feedback.

Comment: @BotHandler the issue happens when you click on the button? If so, do the following, override the MessageReceived of your LuisDialog based class and inspect the text coming, I suspect we are closer...

Comment: Implemented as GlobalMessageHandlers/Scorables (I assumed LuisDialog wont be there in this kind of implementation). Even then I get same error

Comment: @BotHandler stop the ball :) you are not reading our comments. Publish your code in Github so we can take a look

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6c7_QUBM0vTaXU4VjJMZVFsVHc has the similar exception text i get now

Comment: We all know the exception, that was clear :) I already explained the source of the exception; in order to understand why in your code is happening we need to take a look to it and/or we need more details eg: is the issue happening when you click on the button?

Comment: Sorry, i might have missed few comments in between. I will publish code and let know. Got to segregate this piece of code;will do soon. Thanks for the help

Comment: 1) Yes it happens when I click Submit 2) Am not sure why LuisService is called when this is implemented using Scorables and same exception occurs. 3) I will stop confusing further and publish code and let know. Thanks again :)

Comment: @EzequielJadib have published the code here https://github.com/bothandler/AdaptiveCardTest. Kindly take a look. The LUIS Model is in the same folder Authenticate.json

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because when you click on the submit button on Adaptive card it calls the POST method of your BOT Framework. At which time `Activity.Text` field is `NULL`. You should check in the POST method if `Activity.Text` field is `NULL`; if it is, then you should not call LUIS for the intent check.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it, to make it work for Microsoft teams. Else for the emulator, you simply pass a string in Data.

```
dynamic dataObject = new JObject();
dataObject.msteams = new JObject();
dataObject.msteams.type = "imBack";
dataObject.msteams.value = intent.Value;
var actionSubmit = new AdaptiveSubmitAction(){
    Title = intent.Value,
    Data = turnContext.Activity.ChannelId != "emulator" ?  dataObject : intent.Value
};
```